# Send an empty message instead of Embed Discord.Net

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, discord.net

I stated my problem in the title.

code:

```
public static async Task Whois(SocketSlashCommand command)
{
    var guildUser = (SocketGuildUser)command.Data.Options.First().Value;
    var roleList = string.Join(",\n", guildUser.Roles.Where(x => !x.IsEveryone).Select(x => x.Mention));
    var embedBuiler = new EmbedBuilder()
        .WithAuthor(guildUser.ToString(), guildUser.GetAvatarUrl() ?? guildUser.GetDefaultAvatarUrl())
        .WithTitle("Roles")
        .WithDescription(roleList)
        .WithColor(Color.Green)
        .WithCurrentTimestamp();

    await command.RespondAsync(embed: embedBuiler.Build());
}
```

response: [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6tim.png)

I don't know what to do. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible Solution 1**

First, be sure that you show embeds in you discord client.
Go in your settings under Text & Images and activate the [Show embeds and preview website links pasted into chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axp8o.png) setting.

**Possible Solution 2**

As it seems in some [GitHub issues](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/2211) you also have to give your bot the "Embed Link" permission. (Although this doesn't seem to affect slash commands embeds)

**Possible Solution 3**

It is also possible that another bot is removing the embed from you message, so you may want to add a logging bot (to check who is removing the embed) or create a new guild where only your bot is.

---

It's very unlikely that the problem is in your code, as the Discord API doesn't actually allow empty messages to be sent. (although it is possible, if you send for example `_ _` as your message content)